# Subsets of $\Omega$ which are not events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $\Omega = [0,1]$ is my sample space and we have the usual measure on it,
what are some pathological cases (subsets of $\Omega$) which cannot be treated
as events?

I am looking simply for a few examples to better understand which sub-sets can be treated as events and which not.

Obviously if A is e.g. a sub-interval of $\Omega$ or a countable union of sub-intervals, it is an event, we have no problem with it. Right? So which subsets we do have a problem with and thus we cannot treated as events?

Comment: It is not possible to list all Borel sets and it is not possible to given an explicit example of a non-Borel set.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hm... Why not? Then an implicit example maybe?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe You mean there's some relation to the construction of reals as done in real analysis?

Comment: @peter.petrov I precised a little bit how to define such a subset, see my answer !

Answer (score 3):

An usual example of non-Borel subset is the following : consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $[0,1]$ defined by $x \sim y \Longleftrightarrow x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Then consider a subset $A$ of $[0,1]$ constituted of exactly one element from each equivalence class for the relation $\sim$. To show that $A$ is not Borel, do the following :

1. Consider $(r_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ an enumeration of the elements of $\mathbb{Q} \cap (-1,1)$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $A_n = A + r_n$.

2. Show that for $i \neq j$, $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$, and that $$[0,1) \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \subset (-1,2] \quad \quad (*)$$
3. Assuming that $A$ is Borel, show that $A_n$ is also Borel and deduce from $(*)$ that
   $$1 \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lambda(A_n) \leq 3$$

Finally see that  $\lambda(A)=\lambda(A_n)$ for each $n$, to get a contradiction from the last inequalities.

Comment: OK, I will think about this. Are there any other simple constructions?

Comment: I guess there is no "simple" example. In fact, every subset you may imagine naturally will be measurable. Non-Borel are really pathological.

Comment: :) OK thanks... Is there some book which has a section or chapter on that matter? I mean showing some constructions like these.

Comment: @peter.petrov I don't have a lot of reference in English, unfortunately. I don't know what is your general level in measure theory, but if you are at the beginning, a good advice should be to do not worry about non-Borel sets :) Just know that they exist, but you will not see them very often ! Of course, if you are more advanced, these questions are interesting.

Comment: In which language do you have reference? I also know Russian. I am not very advanced level in Lebesque measure theory but I've read this and that. But these things are still interesting to me. I've always stumbled upon them in the first chapters of probability theory books and was never quite able to understand them in full.

Comment: @peter.petrov Ok, I edited my answer, so you can prove by yourself why the example I gave is correct !

Comment: OK... thank you. I will think about this.

Comment: This set is not even Lebesgue measurable...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Isn't that the question ?

Comment: Seems to me that the question could be  referring to Borel sets or Lebesgue measurable sets as events. Regardless of whether the algebra is specified in the question, calling this a construction of a non-Borel set seems silly

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't understand at all why you say that this construction is "silly". The question asks for a non-Borel set, I give a non-Borel set, what is silly here ? I think I am missing something.

Comment: "The question asks for a non-Borel set" really? Given that the word "Borel" does not appear in the question, how do you know that that's what was intended?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The comments below the question do. By the way, an example of non-Borel subset is a valid example of subset which cannot be considered as an event, isn't it ? I genuinely don't get your point.

Comment: Btw I didn't say the construction was silly, I said calling it a construction of a non-Borel set was silly. In the same way that calling a proof of Fermat's Last Theorem a proof that $a^3+b^3\ne c^3$ would be silly. What I don't get is why you object to simply stating that this is actually a construction of a non-Lebesgue-measurable set.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't object to your last statement... But Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable, no ? So if I constructed a non-Lebesgue-measurable set, then I constructed a non-Borel set, no ? What is wrong in saying that the example I gave is an example of a non-Borel set ? Please explain, I really don't see the distinction.

Comment: If this were not a valid construction of a non-Borel set I would have said so.

Comment: Why no ? Aren't Borel sets Lebesgue-measurable ?

Comment: Momentary malfunction, sorry.

Comment: Ok, to be honest I did not really get your point. I just interpreted the question as "can you give an example of non Borel set ?" and I gave such an example (which is even non Lebesgue-measurable, I agree).

Comment: In response to the third comment: is there a book discussing constructions like this, I recommend Stan Wagon's book on the Banch Tarski paradox.