# $\sigma$-algebra of Borel in $\mathbb{R}$ is the power set of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

We define the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel of $\mathbb{R}$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open intervals $(a,b)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $a<b$.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and construct an open interval $I=(a,b)$ such that $x\in I$. Then $x \in (a+\frac{n}{n+1}(x-a),b-\frac{n}{n+1}(b-x))$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

We have $\{x\} = \cap(a+\frac{n}{n+1}(x-a),b-\frac{n}{n+1}(b-x))$. As any $\sigma$-algebra is closed under countable intersections, $\{x\}$ is contained in our $\sigma$-algebra.

We conclude that this $\sigma$-algebra is the power set of $\mathbb{R}$. However, I haven't seen this fact written in any text, so I wonder if my reasoning is wrong. Can anyone confirm or disprove my statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you conclude that "this $\sigma$-algebra is the power set of $\mathbb{R}$" ?

You cannot write any element of the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable union of singletons.

Comment: It seems like I was assuming that you can write any element of the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ as a countable union of singletons, as TheSilverDoe has pointed out. But using Cantor's diagonal argument, we could construct new elements of the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ "beyond" our $\sigma$-algebra. Is this the correct reasoning?

Comment: @Numox My answer just points where your thinking is flawed. But be careful, it does not say that an uncoutable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be in the $\sigma-$algebra (for an obvious example, $\mathbb{R}$ itself is in the $\sigma-$algebra, whereas it is of course not a countable union of singletons !). Actually, you can construct an exemple of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is not in the $\sigma-$algebra, but it is not easy (and not elementary).

Comment: However, this would only disprove my proof of the statement. But how can I assure that there are elements of the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ not included in our $\sigma$-algebra? I understand that we cannot construct some elements through a countable union of singletons, but how do we know that they can't be constructed in any other way "allowed" by the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: @Numox You got it. See my answer on this post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911119/subsets-of-omega-which-are-not-events/3911132#3911132 It gives a way to construct a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is not in the Borel algebra. But as you can see it, it is the simplest example I know, but it is not at all elementary !

Comment: I think that I wrote my second comment while you were writing yours :D

Comment: Thank you! Very useful!

Comment: You are welcome !